# Cannot view the image uploaded on the admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Picture gets uploaded on the django admin panel but when i click on the image on the panel it shows the page not found error.

forms.py

```
class ApproveImgForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ApprovImg
        fields = ['photo']
```

urls.py

```
path('w_p.html', views.WProduct_list, name='WProduct_list'),
```

views.py

```
def WProduct_list(request, category_slug=None):

    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    wproducts = Product.objects.filter()

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        wproducts = Product.objects.filter()

    if(request.method=='POST'):
        form = ApproveImgForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.save()

    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'wproducts': wproducts,
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/w_p.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class ApprovImg(models.Model):
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.photo)
```

w_p.html

```
  <tr>
    <td><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a></td>
    <td> {{ product.price }}</td>
    <td><form action="w_p.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %} 

                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                    <input type="submit">
                  </form>
                </td>
  </tr
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you set `MEDIA_URL` in the settings.py?

Comment: yes i have specified MEDIA_URL in settings.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inherit from ModelForm.

```
class ApproveImgForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = ApprovImg
    fields = "__all__"  # not recommended, you should specify the fields.

# views.py

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApproveImgForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = ApproveImgForm
    return render(request, 'upload_image.html', {'form': form})

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [path('upload', upload_file, name='upload')]

# upload_image.html
<form action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.photo.label_tag }} {{ form.photo.help_text }}</p>
    <p>
        {{ form.photo.errors }}
        {{ form.photo }}
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: I changed it to ModelForm but the image still doesn't open :(

Comment: I did the changes as you said. Now even my html file doesn't open. It shows "The ApprovImg could not be created because the data didn't validate."

Comment: Update the code you have now in the first post and also include the html there, so we can see whats wrong.

Comment: You are referring it wrong in the html file also. I'll edit my response to show you a full example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209627/discussion-between-jabez-and-shyam-parmar).